# Can't load from multiple databases using Spark-Mongo driver

Tags: apache-spark

I am working on spark module, where I need to load the collections from multiple sources (databases) but I can't get the collection from second db.

**Databases**

```
 DB1
  L_coll1
```

```
 DB2
  L_coll2
```

**Logic code**

```
String mst ="local[*]";
        String host= "localhost";
        String port = "27017";
        String DB1 = "DB1";
         String DB2 = "DB2";

         SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("cust data").setMaster(mst);
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                    .builder() 
                    .config(conf)
                     .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://"+host+":"+port+"/")
                     .config("spark.mongodb.input.database",DB1)
                     .config("spark.mongodb.input.collection","coll1")
                    .getOrCreate();

            SparkSession spark1 = SparkSession
                    .builder() 
                    .config(conf)
                     .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://"+host+":"+port+"/")
                     .config("spark.mongodb.input.database",DB2)
                     .config("spark.mongodb.input.collection","coll2")

                    .getOrCreate();

            JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
            JavaSparkContext jsc1 = new JavaSparkContext(spark1.sparkContext());
```

**Reading configurations**

```
ReadConfig readConfig = ReadConfig.create(spark);
            Dataset<Row> MongoDatset =  MongoSpark.load(jsc,readConfig).toDF();

            MongoDatset.show();


            ReadConfig readConfig1 = ReadConfig.create(spark1);
            Dataset<Row> MongoDatset1 =  MongoSpark.load(jsc1,readConfig1).toDF();

            MongoDatset1.show();
```

After running the about code, I am getting the first dataset multiple time. If I comment the first `SparkSession spark` instance than only getting the collection from second db `DB2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the multiple spark sessions you can use `ReadConfig`'s override option to get multiple database and collections.

**Creating spark session**

```
 String DB = "DB1";
 String DB1 = "DB2";
 String Coll1 ="Coll1";
 String Coll2 ="Coll2";

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                  .master("local")
                  .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
                  .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
                  .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
                  .getOrCreate();

                // Create a JavaSparkContext using the SparkSession's SparkContext object
                JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
```

**Get database function**

```
private static Dataset<Row> getDB(JavaSparkContext jsc_, String DB, String Coll1) {
        // Create a custom ReadConfig
        Map<String, String> readOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
        readOverrides.put("database",DB );
        readOverrides.put("collection", Coll1);
        readOverrides.put("readPreference.name", "secondaryPreferred");

        System.out.println(readOverrides);
        ReadConfig readConfig = ReadConfig.create(jsc_).withOptions(readOverrides);

        return   MongoSpark.load(jsc_,readConfig).toDF();

    }
```

**Using getDB to create multiple databases**

```
Dataset<Row> MongoDatset1 = getDB(jsc, DB, Coll1);
Dataset<Row> MongoDatset2 = getDB(jsc, DB1, Coll2);


MongoDatset1.show(1);
MongoDatset2.show(1);
```